# How to make the button clickable even if the clicker doesn't touch the text in the button?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

Basically, I have three buttons as seen in the image below. When I click on the button's actual text, it redirects, but if I click anywhere else inside the button, nothing happens.
[image]

```
 <Button
                variant="outlined"
                size="large"
                color="inherit"
                style={{ marginRight: '1rem' }}
                sx={{
                    ':hover': {
                        opacity: '',
                        borderColor: '#5865f2', // theme.palette.primary.main
                    },
                }}
            >
                <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }} to="/portfolio" className="home-left-portfolio">PortFolio</Link>
            </Button>
```

My goal is to make it redirect regardless of whether we click inside the button's text or not.

Comment: on your link component add this style, width: '100%', height: '100%'

Comment: wrap the button with the `Link`

Comment: It's working thanks!

Comment: "It works" is not the highest bar you can set for yourself though. XD Still, if so, you might want to vote on and select an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap Your Buttons with  < Link > button </ Link >

```
 <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }} to="/portfolio" className="home-left-portfolio">PortFolio
     <Button
                    variant="outlined"
                    size="large"
                    color="inherit"
                    style={{ marginRight: '1rem' }}
                    sx={{
                        ':hover': {
                            opacity: '',
                            borderColor: '#5865f2', // theme.palette.primary.main
                        },
                    }}
                >
                    
                </Button>
    </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }} to="/portfolio" className="home-left-portfolio"><Button
                variant="outlined"
                size="large"
                color="inherit"
                style={{ marginRight: '1rem' }}
                sx={{
                    ':hover': {
                        opacity: '',
                        borderColor: '#5865f2', // theme.palette.primary.main
                    },
                }}
            >
                PortFolio
            </Button>
     </Link>
```

Answer (score -1):

Zamiast

```
<button><link></link></button>
```

sprobuj

```
<link><button></button></link>
```

Powinno pomoc